# Ethernet & Wifi problems Ubuntu 15.10 Lenovo z50

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

I have recently installed ubuntu 15.10 alongside windows 10 on Lenovo z50. I have connected my LAN wire & have a very good internet connection(it runs very well in windows 10). I have configured my proxy settings as well.But in ubuntu it shows wire cable unplugged. Also wifi options are not there.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

output:

# interface(s) file used by ifup(8) & ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

output: 

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

cat /etc/resolv.conf

output:

#Dynamic resolv.conf(s) file for glibic resolver(3) generated by     resolvconf(8)
#      DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

ifconfig -a

output:

enp1s0     link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 28:d2:44:f7:9f:a5
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
               RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0  dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0  txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo               Link  encap:Local Loopback
               inet addr:127.0.0.1   Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr:  ::1/128  Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
               RX packets:9174  errors:0  dropped:0  overruns:0  frame:0
              TX packets:9174  errors:0  dropped:0  overruns:0  carrier:0
               collisions:0  txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:682595 (682.5 KB)  TX bytes:682595 (682.5 KB)
```

I can't determine whether some more settings are required or i don't have drivers. I searched through different forums & blogs, nothing worked Smiley Sad

Any help would be appreciated
Thank You

Comment: what does your /etc/network/interfaces file look like?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My system was lacking updated driver. I installed it & now its working.

Comment: ahh .. good to hear its working now

Comment: Well , you can always answers your own question if you've found a solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the driver required for your computer using

```
lspci
```

In my case:

```
sumit@Lenovo-Z50-70:~/Documents/programs$ lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT   Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev ff)
```

In my case this is Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10). Use the following link for realtek drivers

```
http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false
```

If you don't have an internet connection do it on any other system. Download it & copy it to your system's desktop. Extract it. Open the terminal. Use the commands

```
cd Desktop/r8168-8.041.01 (go to the extracted folder)
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

Enter your password. This will install the driver & connection will be established. If it doesn't work try rebooting your system.

For wifi see this answer if your system has Broadcom Wireless Drivers:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers
```